# Inline google drive video not playing in webview

Tags: android, html, android-studio, webview

My client website http://partidos.online has some embedded videos in his website which are shared from **google drive** but these videos are not playing in my webview. Hre is the URL for video http://partidos.online/video/47. I want to play this *Inline* video in this webview.

this is my Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ....
        ....
    </application>
```

this my MainActivity.java

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewMain);
    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState (PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot play videos by WebView from your Google Drive. I suggest creating new YouTube channel and upload that video there. Then set the URL accordingly to URL of your video on YT.

Comment: but I cannot do anything like this. this is client's website and i only have to make an android app.

Comment: Ok then so why are you trying to make webview for a Google Drive vid?

Comment: This is inline embedded code and i want to show this url http://partidos.online/video/47 as webview shows other pages

Comment: Can you edit your code so we can see if there is not an error in your URL adress passed to the WebView?